# It show the error that Customer is already defined.Please let me know whats wrong and how to correct it

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

**There is a compliation error stating that class name is already define i can't find the way to resolve it**

**further the class name are declared only once and can't find the place where the things are going wrong**

```
package practo;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class Customer     /* compilation error occurs here */
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    void setid(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    int getid()
    {
        return id;
    }
    void setname(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    String getname()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setemail(String email)
    {
        this.email=email;
    }
    String getemail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    void setaddress(String address)
    {
        this.address=address;
    }
    String getaddress()
    {
        return address;
    }
    class PhoneNumber
    {
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String heldFromDate;
        private String heldToDate;
        void setphoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
        {
            this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
        }
        String getphoneNumber()
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        void setheldToDate(String heldToDate)
        {
            this.heldToDate=heldToDate;
        }
        String getheldToDate()
        {
            return heldToDate;
        }

        public String getHeldFromDate() {
            return heldFromDate;
        }
        public void setHeldFromDate(String heldFromDate) {
            this.heldFromDate = heldFromDate;
        }
        class NumberType
        {
            private String code;
            private String description;
            void setcode(String code)
            {
                this.code=code;
            }
            void setdescription(String description)
            {
                this.description=description;
            }
            String getcode()
            {
                return code;
            }
            String getdescription()
            {
                return description;
            }
        }
    }
}

class x1
{
    public void main(String args[])
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Customer c=new Customer();
        Customer.PhoneNumber p=c.new PhoneNumber();
        Customer.PhoneNumber.NumberType n=p.new NumberType();
        System.out.println("Enter the customer details");
        System.out.println("Enter the  id :");
        int id=s.nextInt();
        c.setid(id);
        System.out.println(c.getid());
        System.out.println("Enter the name :");
        String name=s.nextLine();
        c.setname(name);
        System.out.println(c.getname());
        System.out.println("Enter the email :");
        String email=s.nextLine();
        c.setemail(email);
        System.out.println(c.getemail());
        System.out.println("Enter the address :");
        String address=s.nextLine();
        c.setaddress(address);
        System.out.println(c.getaddress());
        System.out.println("Enter the customer contact details");
        System.out.println("Enter the phone number :");
        String phoneNumber=s.nextLine();
        p.setphoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(p.getphoneNumber());
        System.out.println("Enter the held from date (dd/MM/yyyy)  :");
        String heldFromDate=s.next();
        p.setHeldFromDate(heldFromDate);
        System.out.println(p.getHeldFromDate());
        System.out.println("Enter the held to date (dd/MM/yyyy)  :");
        String heldToDate=s.next();
        p.setheldToDate(heldToDate);
        System.out.println(p.getheldToDate());
        System.out.println("Enter number type code :");
        String code=s.next();
        n.setcode(code);
        System.out.println(n.getcode());
        System.out.println("Enter number type description");
        String description=s.next();
        n.setdescription(description);
        System.out.println(n.getdescription());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class does not give me any compilation error. You might try making the class public i.e. `public class Customer` and file name having the name `Customer.java`. It may happen that the package `practo` already contains a class named `Customer`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify Customer class is not duplicate ? If it is not there, can you choose Clean from the Project menu, it might fix these errors.
Sometime eclipse trouble us.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have another class called `Customer` in the package `practo`. That would cause a name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of recommendations for improvement:

1. Open public class per file, and a file for each class.  Your arrangement is confusing.
2. Learn and follow the Java coding standards.
3. Using a Date for a date instead of a String is a better design, especially with JDK 8 and the java.time package.
4. Learn JUnit instead of that x1.main.

These are examples of how your classes should look.

Customer.java

```
    package practo;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 5/29/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511168/it-show-the-error-that-customer-is-already-defined-please-let-me-know-whats-wron
 */
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    public Customer() {
        this(0, "", "", "");
    }

    public Customer(int id, String name, String email, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

PhoneNumber.java:

```
package practo;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 5/29/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511168/it-show-the-error-that-customer-is-already-defined-please-let-me-know-whats-wron
 */
public class PhoneNumber {

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String heldFromDate;  // Bad design.  This ought to be a Date, not a String
    private String heldToDate;    // Bad design.  This ought to be a Date, not a String

    public PhoneNumber() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public PhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, String heldFromDate, String heldToDate) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.heldFromDate = heldFromDate;
        this.heldToDate = heldToDate;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getHeldFromDate() {
        return heldFromDate;
    }

    public void setHeldFromDate(String heldFromDate) {
        this.heldFromDate = heldFromDate;
    }

    public String getHeldToDate() {
        return heldToDate;
    }

    public void setHeldToDate(String heldToDate) {
        this.heldToDate = heldToDate;
    }
}
```